# How would i compare two objects in custom tree set implementation?

Tags: java, collections, binary-search-tree, comparator, comparable

I need to compare two objects in insert method off the tree set. But i am unable to fathom out where and how to implement Comparable or Comparator. My code looks as follows:

This is my Node creation for the binary tree.

```
Node.java

public class Node {

private Object data;
private Node left, right;

//initial case when a Node of a binary tree gets created. both left and right subtrees point to   null
public Node (){

    left = right = null;
}

public Object getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Node getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public void setLeft(Node left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public Node getRight() {
    return right;
}

public void setRight(Node right) {
    this.right = right;
}

}
```

This is my MyBinaryTree class where i need to implement insert method:

```
MyBinaryTree.java

public class MyBinaryTree implements Comparable<Node> {

Node root;

public MyBinaryTree(){
    root = null;
}

void insert(Object x){

    Node newrec = new Node();  //Node constructor gets called and sets up a root node with empty
    //subtrees
    newrec.setData(x);

    if(root == null){
        root = newrec;
    }
    else{
        Node a,b;
        a = b = root;
        while(a!=null){
            b=a;   
            if( ( newrec.getData() ).compareTo( a.getData() ) ) {
```

i am stuck here! how would i compare these objects using Comparable?

```
            }
        }

    }

}

void inorder(Node root){

}

@Override
public int compareTo(Node o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i = (o.)
    return 0;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be able to compare, not just nodes, but the data contained in those nodes. That means that your `Node` either needs to be limited to taking objects that are `Comparable,` or your tree needs to take a `Comparator` that it can use to compare them.

If you really want to support both, then when the time comes to do the comparison, if a `Comparator` has been provided, use its compare method, otherwise cast the data to `Comparable<? super E>` where E is the type of Node data (see below), and then use its `compareTo` method.

That brings me to the next point. Your `Node` class should probably not simply contain `Object` as its data, but instead be declared as `Node<E> implements Comparable<Node<E>>,` and then your tree can be declared as `MyBinaryTree<E>.` I would also change the constructor for `Node` to take the data as a parameter, rather than calling the setter immediately after creating one. There is no reason you would ever want to create a `Node` with no data.

I would strongly suggest looking through the source code for some of the generic collections in the `java.util` package, which comes with the JDK. In particular, I referred to the source of `TreeMap.java` to see how they handled both Comparable and non-Comparable elements, since the class isn't declared in such a way as to require the elements to be Comparable. (If they aren't, and there is no `Comparator,` a `ClassCastException` would occur where they try to cast the object to `Comparable<? super K>`.) Seeing how they have implemented similar code will be a great help to you. You may also want to review Java generics.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code

```
package com.example.treeset;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MyCompUser {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        //By using name comparator (String comparison)
        TreeSet<Empl> nameComp = new TreeSet<Empl>(new MyNameComp());
        nameComp.add(new Empl("Ram",3000));
        nameComp.add(new Empl("John",6000));
        nameComp.add(new Empl("Crish",2000));
        nameComp.add(new Empl("Tom",2400));
        for(Empl e:nameComp){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("===========================");
        //By using salary comparator (int comparison)
        TreeSet<Empl> salComp = new TreeSet<Empl>(new MySalaryComp());
        salComp.add(new Empl("Ram",3000));
        salComp.add(new Empl("John",6000));
        salComp.add(new Empl("Crish",2000));
        salComp.add(new Empl("Tom",2400));
        for(Empl e:salComp){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class MyNameComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
    }
}   

class MySalaryComp implements Comparator<Empl>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Empl e1, Empl e2) {
        if(e1.getSalary() > e2.getSalary()){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

class Empl{

    private String name;
    private int salary;

    public Empl(String n, int s){
        this.name = n;
        this.salary = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+this.name+"-- Salary: "+this.salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: You ought to describe the issue better than "Please refer below code"